# Would CTCs in wormholes change physical laws?

Tags: spacetime, computational-physics, wormholes, closed-timelike-curve

A wormhole is a speculative structure linking disparate points in spacetime, and is based on a special solution of the Einstein field equations solved using a Jacobian matrix and determinant.

(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wormhole)

A Closed Timelike Curve (CTC) is is a world line in a Lorentzian manifold, of a material particle in spacetime that is "closed", returning to its starting point. These would theoretically make time travel possible and could be used to perform hypercomputation.

(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed_timelike_curve)
(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypercomputation)

> GR solutions containing CTCs have been found, such as the Tipler cylinder and traversable wormholes

Since wormholes could contain CTCs and they could lead to hypercomputational processes and consequences, could these wormholes have laws and constants of physics based on hypercomputational principles?

Comment: What do you mean by "laws and constants of physics based on hypercomputational principles"? If wormhole CTCs exist they allow certain forms of exotic computation, but that would just mean physics allows these forms, it does not change what physics is.

Comment: @AndersSandberg, oh, okay, that's where I wanted to go. So, CTCs would not make physics itself "hypercomputational" inside a wormhole

Comment: @AndersSandberg and if not, then, what about Schmidhuber's theories of everything based on Chaitin's constant? (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaitin%27s_constant): " Jürgen Schmidhuber (2000) constructed a limit-computable "Super Ω" which in a sense is much more random than the original limit-computable Ω, as one cannot significantly compress the Super Ω by any enumerating non-halting algorithm" Would his theories be based on hypercomputation?

Comment: @AndersSandberg More information about Schmidhuber's hypothesis: "(...)he expanded this work by combining Ray Solomonoff's theory of inductive inference with the assumption that quickly computable universes are more likely than others. This work on digital physics also led to limit-computable generalizations of algorithmic information or Kolmogorov complexity and the concept of Super Omegas, which are limit-computable numbers that are even more random (in a certain sense) than Gregory Chaitin's number of wisdom Omega." (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_physics)

Comment: @AndersSandberg "A symbol sequence is computable in the limit if there is a finite, possibly non-halting program on a universal Turing machine that incrementally outputs every symbol of the sequence. This includes the dyadic expansion of π and of every other computable real, but still excludes all noncomputable reals. Traditional Turing machines cannot edit their previous outputs; generalized Turing machines, as defined by Jürgen Schmidhuber, can..."

Comment: @AndersSandberg "...He defines the constructively describable symbol sequences as those that have a finite, non-halting program running on a generalized Turing machine, such that any output symbol eventually converges;that is, it does not change any more after some finite initial time interval. Due to limitations first exhibited by Kurt Gödel (1931), it may be impossible to predict the convergence time itself by a halting program, otherwise the halting problem could be solved..."

Comment: @AndersSandberg "..Schmidhuber uses this approach to define the set of formally describable or constructively computable universes or constructive theories of everything. Generalized Turing machines can eventually converge to a correct solution of the halting problem by evaluating a Specker sequence" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypercomputation)

Comment: @sztowi - What does Schmidhuber's work have to do with CTCs?

Comment: @AndersSandberg Since you seem to tell me that CTCs do not have to do anything with changing the fundamental laws of the universe where they exist, I was looking for other alternatives of universes based on hypercomputational laws

Comment: Sure, there are many models of hypercomputation. But note that they are not equivalent. What you get from CTCs https://www.scottaaronson.com/papers/ctc.pdf is very different from the Solomonoff induction models. And it is pretty likely neither can be implemented in our physics.

Comment: @AndersSandberg Also, Gödel's universe, which would have CTCs, could be globally non-hyperbollic given certain conditions. Could a Gödel's universe then, in that case, have hypercomputational laws and rules (based on hypercomputation)? (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del_metric)

Comment: Gödel universes presumably get the Aaronson computational capacity.

Comment: @AndersSandberg I think I should distinguish here what I mean by laws based on hypercomputation: CTCs allow hypercomputation to occur, but the fundamental laws in (normal) Gödel universes (and other metrics that are solutions to Einstein's field equations) would be based basically on general relativity. What I am asking is: Could one of these metrics produce a universe where its fundamental laws would be based on hypercomputation (and instead of being described by relativity, they would be described by hypercomputational processes)?

Comment: @AndersSandberg In summary, could one of these metrics describe a hypercomputer-universe?: (Non-hyperbolic) Gödel's metric, Kerr metric, Kerr-Newman metric and Anti de Sitter space? Could at least one of them produce a universe which its laws themselves would be based on hypercomputation (instead of just allowing hypercomputation to occur but described by "normal" or computable physical laws like general relativity)?